# How many ways can the 3 pairs of socks be arranged on the line without restriction?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

The answer is $90$.

But why cant we just choose a sock for the first position in $6$ ways, second position in $5$ ways and so on so it would be $6!$?

Comment: Socks are in pairs so we will have to divide by $(2!)^3$ as 6 socks have 3 pairs.

Comment: The key to questions involving arrangements of socks, coloured balls, and such, is that they are asking you to count distinguishable patterns.  They *also* assume people somehow cannot tell their left socks apart from their right socks.

Answer (score 3):

Think that they are distinct.

That is they are completely different from each other .

So then you would get the answer $6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1=6!$

But they are identical in pairs.

So one permutation repeats 2! times.

So you have to divide by $2!\times 2!\times 2!$ to get the answer.